# copy linux git directory to windows cause errror "fatal: bad object header"

Tags: git, msysgit

I tried to move a git work directory from linux to windows with targz

- I checked the archive and if I untar the file on linux, git status works fine.
- i installed msysgit with bash on windows.
- I untar the archive
- I call git status
  then it returns "fatal: bad object header"

NOTE: After googling, I found corruption issue causing this error but no mention of incompatiblity between Linux and Windows.
I am working with Ubuntu 12.04 64bits and Windows XP Pro 32bits English edition.

Comment: I don't know msysgit much, but do you have `md5sum` installed on both the Linux and Windows host? Try and md5sum all the .git directory. Also, why don't you just `git clone` from the Linux machine?

Comment: No idea on the error, but just use git facilities to clone the repo.

Comment: There is no GIT server. Just me developing on linux and sending the tarball to my customer.

Comment: @lenzai You don't need a special "GIT server"; if you've got a git repository on a linux box running SSH, you can clone from it with `git clone youruser@your.ip.address:/path/to/git/repo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copying data will not work, you will have to use git clone to copy repository on windows machine.

Comment: since both machines aren't connected and there is no shared server. How can I do that ?
At some point, I will need to transfer the file through email anyway.